# MP4 structure - ISO and QuickTime understanding

Tags: video, mp4, h.264, iso, quicktime

I have a purpose to stream an h264 video from RTP packets to a web page through  `MPEG-DASH` technology.

I know about RTP and H264 structures, I work with them. 
For the `MPEG-DASH`, I read that it supports a special type of `.mp4` file. 
To dive deeper in this task I decided to begin research "mux" `h264` into `.mp4` single file. Then I'm going to write my own muxer.

And I found a huge question encouraged me:

**What is the difference between QuickTime `.mp4` and ISO-based (ISO/IEC 14496-12,14) `.mp4`?**

I found they have the same origin, but what is for now?
They have different documentation with ISO-box/QT-atom description.

As Apple’s QuickTime document is more clear about `.mp4`, can I write my mp4 encoder according to it for MPEG-DASH?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Forget QuickTime. Just look at 14496-12. Look at the w3c page for MSE for a link.